# SAP UI5 IconTabBar stretchContentHeight overlapping

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add a panel and ProgressIndicator above IconTabBar and want only scrolling enable for the IconTabBar conten. As per documentation, stretchContentHeight should do the magic, but in my case, the panel/ProgressIndicator is overlapping on Tabs. Any suggestions to make it work?

Refer this link to sample code: https://plnkr.co/edit/FeDd0cvYXcIpmqHP8Inh?p=preview

```
        <IconTabBar
        id="idIconTabBarStretchContent"
        stretchContentHeight="true">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Layouts](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/floorplan-overview/), in your case I would prefer Object Page Layout ([Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2e61ab6c68a2480eb666c1927a707658), [API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout), [Samples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout)).
Check out the updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/876ZbpmPo5fxy2wMXLAr?p=preview).

Modifications:

1. Adding ObjectPageLayout using the Tab navigation mode with LazyLoading and alwaysShowContentHeader property set to true
2. Moving original content of `IconTabBar.view` into a separate view `Products.view`
3. Modifying Page content height to 100% in `index.html`

.

```
content: [ new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
    height : "100%", name : "sap.m.sample.IconTabBarStretchContent"
})]
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. The solution is pretty close to what I need. Is it possible to keep the panel and ProgressIndicator fixed? Right now it scrolls and hides once we scroll up.

Comment: Add [`alwaysShowContentHeader="true"`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout/methods/getAlwaysShowContentHeader) to ObjectPageLayout